# Hotmail Account Hacked, No Phone Code

Tags: outlook.com

One of my associates had their Hotmail account broadcasting spam, and presumably hacked. They managed to change the password, but after that, the account got locked; Hotmail asks you for a phone number, and they're supposed to call you with a code.

This person requested the code several times, with different numbers (even two of mine!), but never received any call with the confirmation code.

I referred them to the full-length process, which includes answering the security question; apparently, they forgot their question (having entered it over a decade ago and never reviewed it since).

What options, if any, exist to restore access to this person's account? They only want to grab their contacts; they plan to operate full-force on GMail going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should raise a request over at [this form](https://windowslivehelp.com/ask.aspx).

> If you are unable to verify using the SMS validation, please submit
>   your request [here](https://windowslivehelp.com/ask.aspx)(Select "Hotmail" from the product dropdown
>   list, click “Continue” and select: Error: "Your account has been
>   temporarily blocked") and one of our moderators will help you.

Comment: You need to complain on their forums to get a response. It takes a long time (took me over a month).