# My Hotmail Account

Tags: google-account, outlook.com, alias

﻿I need help with my account I accidentally deleted my primary email alias that I Been using for many years when I added a new one it used to be my old email address and now it's a different one with @gmail.com and I want it back to @ hotmail.com and I want it back as it’s registered everywhere. I tried all that I could. Please help!! It’s very important

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hotmail Account Hacked, No Phone Code](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20159/hotmail-account-hacked-no-phone-code)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove Gmail as as service from your Google Account in order to be able to use an email address from a non-Google service as the Google Account primary email address.

Related

- [Can the primary email of a Google account be changed to something other than the Gmail address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1119/88163)
- [How to set my alternate (non-Gmail) address as the account primary?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57512/88163)
- [Created new Gmail account while logged in with non-Gmail email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93084/88163)